# ¿Cómo hacer clic a un botón que está en internet desde Excel usando querySelector?

Tags: html, excel, vba, dom, internet-explorer

He buscado pero no encuentro nada de como hacer clic en un botón que está en una página de internet (les dejo el HTML abajo). Ya lo intenté con `getElementByClassName` pero resulta que en la página hay un botón con la misma clase y la misma etiqueta, si me pudieran ayudar se los agradeceria mucho.

Este es el botón al que quiero hacer clic.

```
<input type="submit" value="Request&nbsp;Price" class="button" onmouseover="checkState()" onclick="event.returnValue=false;(helpState)? getHelp(event,'hlp_601'):event.returnValue=true" style="cursor: help;">
```

Este el HTML del otro botón que se está ejecutando en vez del que quiero.

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" class="button" onmouseover="checkState()" onclick="javascript:(helpState)? getHelp(event,'hlp_600'):window.location.href='Priceller?userAction=new'" style="cursor: help;">
```

La forma en la que lo estoy tratando de llamar es de la siguiente, pero no me funciona:

```vb
Sub navegacion()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim pagina As HTMLDocument
Dim pagina2 As HTMLDocument

'crea el explorador de internet en Medium, porque solo no funcionaba.
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

'hacemos visible el explorador
ie.Visible = True

'navega a la URL1
ie.navigate "URL1"

'espera a que la página cargue
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

'la página cargada la asignamos a la variable "pagina"
Set pagina = ie.document

'asignamos el valor del usuario
pagina.getElementById("userName").Value = Range("USUARIO").Value

'pasamos la contraseña
pagina.getElementById("passwd").Value = Range("CONTRASEÑA").Value

'seleccionamos el botón de ingreso y hacemos click
pagina.getElementsByClassName("submit")(0).Click

'asignamos a una variable el estado de la página
stat = pagina.readyState

'Espera a que la página cargue
Do While stat = "loading"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    stat = pagina.readyState
Loop

'Aquí hago una comparación porque después de loguearme la URL cambia y 
necesito otros datos de esta URL2
If pagina.URL <> "URL1" Then

'navega a la URL2
ie.navigate "URL2"

'espera a que la página cargue
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

'la página cargada la asignamos a la variable "pagina2"
Set pagina2 = ie.document

pagina2.getElementById("dato1").Value = Range("dato1").Value

pagina2.getElementById("dato2").Value = Range("dato2").Value

pagina2.getElementById("dato3").Value = Range("dato3").Value

'Aqui es donde no puedo hacer el click para que mande esa información
****pagina2.querySelector("input.button").Click****
'asignamos a una variable el estado de la página    
stat2 = pagina2.readyState

'espera a que la página cargue
Do While stat2 = "loading"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    stat2 = pagina2.readyState
Loop
    End If

End Sub
```

¿Cómo se podría hacer?

Comment: prueba con `getElementsByTagName("input")[2].click()`

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo recuerda que el primer elemento empieza en 0 por lo tanto si pone el 2 seria seleccionar el tercero

Comment: @JuankGlezz Asumo que lo sabe, ya que ha probado con números del **0** al 10. jajaja saludos =)

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo al poner código entre corchetes, me marca un error que dice **Compile error: Expected: end of statement**

Comment: ¿Cómo estas declarando pagina2? Además, deberías incluir un [mcve].

Comment: Hola @Rubén ya agregué el ejemplo arriba, no se si cumple todas las reglas para ser mínimo, completo y verificable, pero espero que así quede más claro mi problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si bien una forma de hacer pruebas es variar manualmente los indices, uno como programador no debería estar adivinando el índice requerido. En cualquier caso, en lugar de usar getElementsByTagName usa [querySelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288169(v=vs.85).aspx) ya que este además de la etiqueta permite especificar atributos y sus valores.

En la reciente edición mencionas que el elemento objetivo es

```
<input type="submit" value="Request&nbsp;Price" class="button" onmouseover="checkState()" onclick="event.returnValue=false;(helpState)? getHelp(event,'hlp_601'):event.returnValue=true" style="cursor: help;">
```

Cambia

```
****pagina2.querySelector("input.button").Click****
```

por

```
pagina2.querySelector("input[type=submit]").Click
```

Por otro lado en el código falta una sentencia para validar que la página cargada tenga la estructura esperada.

Comment: Rubén, la forma en la que respondí como comentario, ¿es valido?

Comment: @JoséManuel: Siendo estrictos no se debe responder como comentario, se debe usar las respuestas para responder, (véase [answer] )los comentarios para comentar (te debo el enlace al artículo de ayuda sobre comentarios)

Comment: Rubén, crees que la pregunta debe continuar así o formular una nueva ya que el problema no solo es dar click en un botón, si no que existe este problema de doble etiqueta y doble classname, o no conocer alguna solución?

Comment: Edita la pregunta. Me parece que no estás sacando provecho de querySelector como podrías.

Comment: Rubén, ya edite el contenido, espero que resulte más claro, tienes alguna idea de como podría hacer para solucionar mi problema?

Comment: Ya actualicé mi respuesta. Prueba con lo que te sugiero.

Comment: Rubén, funciono muy bien, de verdad muchas por la ayuda, si hay alguna manera de recompensarte no dudes en decirlo, saludos.

Comment: Que bueno que te funcionó. La forma en la que decimos gracias aquí es votando positivo, aceptando la respuesta, respondiendo una pregunta de quien te respondió o la de alguien más. Más detalles en [¿Qué hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61968/discussion-between-jose-manuel-and-ruben).

Comment: tengo otra pregunta que hice como una nueva https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86136/c%C3%B3mo-extraer-texto-al-final-de-una-etiqueta-html-desde-excel crees que se pueda obtener la información con `querySelector`