# Extraer información de Internet Explorer desde Excel con VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, dom, internet-explorer

Tengo un código que estoy haciendo en VBA para que simule a un usuario ponga usuario, password y de enter, después que llene un formulario con información y de enter, después cuando tenga la información lista copie y pegue elementos en en la hoja de Excel.

```vb
Sub navegación()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim pagina As HTMLDocument
Dim pagina2 As HTMLDocument
Dim pagina3 As HTMLDocument

'crea el explorador de internet lo puse como Medium que InternetExplorer no me cargaba
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

'hacemos visible el explorador
ie.Visible = True

'navega a la página
ie.navigate "URL para poner usuario y contraseña"

'espera a que la página cargue
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

'la página cargada la asignamos a la variable "pagina"
Set pagina = ie.document

'asignamos el valor del usuario
pagina.getElementById("userName").Value = Range("B1").Value

'esperamos un segundo para que puedas visualizar los cambios que estas realizando
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

'pasamos la contraseña
pagina.getElementById("passwd").Value = Range("B2").Value
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

'seleccionamos el botón de buscar y hacemos click
pagina.getElementsByClassName("button")(0).Click

'asignamos a una variable el estado de la página
stat = pagina.readyState

'Espera a que la página cargue
Do While stat = "loading"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    stat = pagina.readyState
Loop

'Aquí hago la comparación porque el URL cambia después de que entra ya a la intranet.
If pagina.Url <> "URL para poner usuario y contraseña" Then

'Asignamos el nuevo URL
ie.navigate "URL para ingresar datos para consulta"

'Esperamos a que cargue
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
End If

'la página cargada la asignamos a la variable "pagina2"
Set pagina2 = ie.document

'Agregamos comprador.
pagina2.getElementById("fif1").Value = Range("B3").Value
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

'Agregamos vendedor.
pagina2.getElementById("fif2").Value = Range("B4").Value
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

'Agregamos numero de producto.
pagina2.getElementById("fif3").Value = Range("B5").Value
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

'Acemos click para que busque la información.
pagina2.querySelector("input[type=submit]").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

'asignamos a una variable el estado de la página
stat2 = pagina2.readyState

'Espera a que la página cargue
Do While stat2 = "loading"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    stat2 = pagina2.readyState
Loop

'Condicional porque después de la búsqueda de nuevo cambia el URL
If pagina2.Url <> "URL para ingresar datos para consulta" Then

'Asignamos el nuevo URL
ie.navigate "URL con datos a extraer"

'Esperamos a que cargue
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
End If

'la página cargada la asignamos a la variable "pagina3"
Set pagina3 = ie.document
```

**aquí es donde me genera error, no se como traer la información de la pagina y inspeccionando los elementos el HTML está abajo, el error que me genera es que corre sin error pero al final no me da el resultado que quiero, sólo pone un texto que dice [object].**

```vb
'aquí declaro el valor que quiero traer para después poner la información en el.
Dim CP As String

'Declaro la colección de elementos que me devolvera querySelectorAll
Dim coleccionDeAlgo As IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection

'Obtener todas las etiquetas td y la clase
pagina3.querySelectorAll ("td.resultBlack")

'pagina3 con todas las etiquetas cargadas se convierte a una colección
Set coleccionDeAlgo = pagina3.querySelectorAll("td.resultBlack")

'primer valor que queremos extraer
CP = coleccionDeAlgo(0)
Range("B6").Value = CP

End Sub
```

Estoy buscando extraer texto especifico al final de varias etiquetas HTML y estos datos pegarlos en Excel en una celda en especifico, he buscado pero no encuentro información.

Este es el HTML en *** marque de donde quiero sacar la información, es una tabla que tiene 10 elementos con la misma estructura de etiqueta `td` y la clase `resultBlack` lo que quiero es poder sacar el numero que está al final entre `help;">`y `</td>`

```
<tbody><tr><td colspan="5" height="15"></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="157" align="left"><span onmouseover="checkState()" onclick="getHelp(event,&quot;hlp_505&quot;)">C&nbsp;P&nbsp;(CP)</span></td>
    <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
    ***<td class="resultBlack" onmouseover="checkState()" onclick="getHelp(event,&quot;hlp_505&quot;)" style="cursor: help;">1.1652</td>
    <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>***
</tr>

</tbody>
```

si hay alguna modificación extra a la forma de redacción o desarrollo del contenido también es bienvenida.

¿cómo se podría hacer lo anterior?

Comment: Dice "aquí es donde me genera error, no se como traer la información de la pagina y inspeccionando los elementos el HTML está abajo" pero no dice cuál es el error ¿Cuál es? Por otro lado, intenta crear un [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén ya encontré la solución con querySelectorAll, como podría replantear mi pregunta para que pueda ser útil para alguien más? del mismo modo, en la pregunta pongo como lo solucione o como se procede?

Comment: La solución deberías publicarla como una respuesta. En cuanto a la forma de replantear el problema, lo que te decía en el comentario anterior, crea un [mcve]. ¿Lo has leído el artículo? Si tienes dudas sobre este pregunta en [meta] o en el [chat].

Comment: @Rubén ya quedó la modificación tanto de la pregunta como del contenido espero que sea de utilidad para alguien más, lo único es que algunas veces al ejecutarlo me marca un error de `Object variable or with block variable not set` en la linea de `C.Value = coleccion.innerText` como podría hacerle para que ya no ocurra, esto sucede en el código que deje como respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por el aviso. Si en ocasiones ocurre y en otras no, podría tratarse de que se deba a que en ocasiones demora más tiempo en cargar la página. Una forma es que después de cada "wait" tu código verifique que la página se cargado completamente, y en caso contrario, espere otro tanto. Inténtalo y si requieres mayor orientación, publica una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias @Rubén

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa [querySelectorAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304115(v=vs.85).aspx) el cual te va a devolver una colección. Para obtener cada uno de los elementos usa un índice, 0 para el primero, 1 para el segundo y así sucesivamente.

También tienes como alternativas el usar los otros selectores como getElementsByTagName, getElementsByClassName, etc. La selección depende de que tan bien conozcas la estructura de la página, lo cual debería ser uno de tus objetivos, la estructura misma de esta y tus preferencias personales.

Comment: Rubén estoy tratando de ejecutarlo de la forma siguiente, pero no se si mi sintaxis es corrrecta ya que me marca error.  `pagina3.querySelectorAll("td")(0).Copy
Range("B6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Comment: Rubén he modificado el código que pongo en la pregunta, espero que ayude para que tengas más claridad y me puedas ayudar.

Comment: Me parece que cambiaste mucho la pregunta y ahora esta respuesta se ha vuelto "off-topic".

Answer (score 1):

Con la ayuda de Rubén y utilizando `querySelectorAll` logre obtener la información que necesitaba, les dejo aquí el código por si a alguien le puede servir,

```vb
'Declaro la colección que se va a obtener con querySelectorAll como IHTMLElement
Dim coleccion As IHTMLElement
Dim coleccion2 As IHTMLElement

'Se declaran las celdas donde se pegara la información.
Dim C As Range
Dim T As Range

'Se convierte a objeto la celda que se va a ocupar. 
Set C = Sheet1.Range("B6")
Set T = Sheet1.Range("B7")

'Se limpian las celdas.
CP.Clear
TC.Clear

'Con querySelectorAll se obtiene de la etiqueta td con clase "resultBlack" el indice 0
Set coleccion = pagina3.querySelectorAll(".resultBlack")(0)
'Se pega el resultado en la celda.
C.Value = coleccion.innerText

'Con querySelectorAll se obtiene de la etiqueta td con clase "resultBlack" el indice 8
Set coleccion2 = pagina3.querySelectorAll(".resultBlack")(8)
T.Value = coleccion2.innerText
```